# Oracle Function to update a table, if the record is null then INSERT

Tags: php, oracle, procedure

I am new here and I am a newbie in learning oracle. 
I am trying to make an oracle function to perform a task on a table. So, what im trying to achieve is, when user supplied values, it has to check in the table,

1. if the record exists based on one value then update the rest of the columns
2. if the record is not exists then insert a row based on the supplied values.

I have this table

```
CREATE TABLE WELTESADMIN.MST_ERC_UPD
(
  PROJECT_NAME    VARCHAR2(25 CHAR)             NOT NULL,
  HEAD_MARK       VARCHAR2(25 CHAR)             NOT NULL,
  COLI_NUM        VARCHAR2(30 CHAR)             NOT NULL,
  ONSITE_UPD_QTY  NUMBER(38)                    NOT NULL,
)
```

and the SQL,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE WELTESADMIN.SP_MST_ERC_UPD
(
    p_HEAD_MARK IN MST_ERC_UPD.HEAD_MARK%TYPE,
    p_PROJECT_NAME IN MST_ERC_UPD.PROJECT_NAME%TYPE,
    p_COLI_NUM IN MST_ERC_UPD.COLI_NUM%TYPE,
    p_ONSITE_UPD_QTY IN MST_ERC_UPD.ONSITE_UPD_QTY%TYPE
)
IS
BEGIN
IF (SELECT HEAD_MARK, PROJECT_NAME, COLI_NUM FROM MST_ERC_UPD) IS NULL
    THEN 
        INSERT INTO MST_ERC_UPD (HEAD_MARK, PROJECT_NAME, COLI_NUM)
    VALUES (p_HEAD_MARK, p_PROJECT_NAME,  p_COLI_NUM, p_ONSITE_UPD_QTY)
ELSE
UPDATE MST_ERC_UPD 
    SET 
        ONSITE_UPD_QTY = p_ONSITE_UPD_QTY
    WHERE
        HEAD_MARK = p_HEAD_MARK AND
        PROJECT_NAME = p_PROJECT_NAME AND
        COLI_NUM = p_COLI_NUM;
COMMIT;
END SP_MST_ERC_UPD;
```

So what im trying to do is based on 3 variables HEAD_MARK, PROJECT_NAME and COLI_NUM. When user submit a form then 4 values are passed and do the processing in the server. If those 3 (HEAD_MARK, PROJECT_NAME, COLI_NUM)are present in the database then insert into database with the ONSITE_UPD_QTY. And if present then update the ONSITE_UPD_QTY only.

I am just learning and i cant make this procedure work in SQL Developer. I am planning to use it in PHP and call this procedure when user submit the form. Please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. if the record exists based on one value then update the rest of the columns
> 2. if the record is not exists then insert a row based on the supplied values.

All you need is **MERGE** statement. Both your requirements could be done at one go.

The syntax is -

```
MERGE INTO table_a a
  USING table_b b
    ON (a.column= b.column)
  WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET a.column= b.column
  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (column1, column2)
    VALUES (b.val1, b.val2);
```

**Update** Example to show USING clause for procedure parameters

```
USING(
SELECT
p_HEAD_MARK hm, 
p_PROJECT_NAME pn, 
p_COLI_NUM cn, 
p_ONSITE_UPD_QTY ouq
FROM DUAL) s
```

Use these as `s.hm, s.pn, s.cn, s.ouq`

**Update 2** A complete test case

Let's say I have a table `emp1` with no rows. I create a procedure which takes `ename` as INPUT, which I will use to insert into `emp` table using **MERGE**.

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM emp1;

no rows selected

SQL>
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE
  2  PROCEDURE p(
  3      p_ename IN VARCHAR2)
  4  AS
  5  BEGIN
  6    MERGE INTO emp1 e USING
  7    (SELECT p_ename AS ename FROM dual
  8    ) s ON(e.ename = s.ename)
  9  WHEN MATCHED THEN
 10    UPDATE SET e.empno = 100 WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
 11    INSERT
 12      (ename
 13      ) VALUES
 14      (s.ename
 15      );
 16  END;
 17  /

Procedure created.

SQL>
SQL> sho err
No errors.
SQL>
SQL> BEGIN
  2    p('SCOTT');
  3  END;
  4  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Let's see if the value got inserted.

```
SQL> SELECT ename FROM emp1;

ENAME
----------
SCOTT

SQL>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but if i want to put this inside a function or procedure which one should i choose ? function or procedure ?

Comment: ideally you should not do DML inside function. You can do it in procedure. Use the IN parameters in the `USING CLAUSE as (select param_list from DUAL)`

Comment: lalit... your sql query assumes that it has two table using table b. but im only using variables to update or insert. I h ave only one table MST_ERC_UPD

Comment: That is why I said, in the USING clause, instead of table, you need to write a SQL to select the parameters from dual. See this https://community.oracle.com/thread/2277205

Comment: So if we are  using select the parameters from dual, do we need to supply column name or direct variable as in "HM1"; SELECT (B."HM1" FROM DUAL B)? Im kinda lost here