# Oracle insert or update. if there is no record then INSERT; Else UPDATE

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I can get this procedure to run,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE WELTESADMIN.SP_MST_ERC_UPD
(
    p_HEAD_MARK IN MST_ERC_UPD.HEAD_MARK%TYPE,
    p_PROJECT_NAME IN MST_ERC_UPD.PROJECT_NAME%TYPE,
    p_COLI_NUM IN MST_ERC_UPD.COLI_NUM%TYPE,
    p_ONSITE_UPD_QTY IN MST_ERC_UPD.ONSITE_UPD_QTY%TYPE,
    p_PREP_UPD_QTY IN MST_ERC_UPD.PREP_UPD_QTY%TYPE,
    p_ERECT_UPD_QTY IN MST_ERC_UPD.ERECT_UPD_QTY%TYPE,
    p_QC_UPD_QTY IN MST_ERC_UPD.QC_UPD_QTY%TYPE
)
IS
BEGIN
UPDATE MST_ERC_UPD 
    SET 
        ONSITE_UPD_QTY = p_ONSITE_UPD_QTY,
        PREP_UPD_QTY = p_PREP_UPD_QTY,
        ERECT_UPD_QTY = p_ERECT_UPD_QTY,
        QC_UPD_QTY = p_QC_UPD_QTY
    WHERE
        HEAD_MARK = p_HEAD_MARK AND
        PROJECT_NAME = p_PROJECT_NAME AND
        COLI_NUM = p_COLI_NUM;
COMMIT;
END SP_MST_ERC_UPD;
```

This is only the update. What I am trying to achieve is, when a row with 3 variables HEAD_MARK, PROJECT_NAME, COLI_NUM happen to be exists exactly in a table, it should update the value, otherwise it should INSERT a new row with the supplied value. How do i add IF, ELSE so that the operation is executed based on those 2 conditions ?

thanks a lot

Comment: I have already answered your question here [Oracle Function to update a table, if the record is null then INSERT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28104376/oracle-function-to-update-a-table-if-the-record-is-null-then-insert)

Answer (score 4):

Oracle support `merge` statement. You can use `merge` to avoid multiple `insert`, `update`, and `delete` statements.

Please refer to the following URL:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_9016.htm#SQLRF01606

Comment: There is a complete answer for this duplciate question here http://stackoverflow.com/a/28104555/3989608